# I can't download file sql, how to fix it ? thanks

Tags: phpmyadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7zzd.png)

when I export the sql file, it says "couldn't download, network issue" error, if i press continue, it will output html file

Comment: Could you please tell us your PHP and phpMyAdmin versions?

Answer (score 1):

Without specific PHP and phpMyAdmin versions there could be other causes, but this seems like a bug that's already been reported as https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17445. My understanding is that something changed with how PHP is sending header information and that's affecting the file download. The next phpMyAdmin release should include a fix for this.